# RPC: Asking for TX info while blockchain still not synced

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, json-rpc

I am wondering whether geth looks inside the network to search for the Tx. Or is it doing everything locally (i.e. looks inside blockchain on disk)?

For example, consider this UseCase:

1) I have installed fresh geth.

2) Started geth with RPC enabled (it starts to sync):

`geth --testnet --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"`

3) Calling some RPC methods, like 'show me balance of the address' or 'show TX info'.

**Question**:
If blockchain sync is still not complete -> will it show me the correct values?

Answer (score 2):

Geth needs to be synced to show correct values: it only looks at its local blockchain.

Note: It's best to avoid `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"` or even enabling RPC on a server that has real ether.

Comment: Thx! I'm using testnet server so it is OK to be open.